# Android HTTP request

Tags: java, php, android

In my app I need a feature that means users can email me by filling in a field. This sends via a HTTP request to a PHP script on my server. This then grabs the message and emails me.

What I need to be able to do if it is even possible is to have a way for the PHP script to confirm that the request originates from a Android device or even better a mobile device.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, RiaD was talking about user agent, and I think that's actually the way to go !
If I understand correctly, your app sends an http request. I assume your app isn't a web view !

If you send an httpRequest, you are using an httpClient to send it.

You'll just have to write this :

```
myHttpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "MyCustomAndroidUserAgent");
```

And then, use this httpClient to send the httpRequest.
Like that, if your php script is triggered by a request using that agent, you can assume that it came from an android device...

Answer (score 0):

There are *no* way to 100% determine is browser from mobile or not

You can try to analize `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`, but be noticed that it's easy to change  it to any string.
Added: Usually browsers add info about OS in UserAgent i.e. you can search for `Android` in this string

Also you may be able to collect IPs of mobile operators and check is user IP in your base.

Comment: cheers for the advice, I was aware that there are no full proof way, just wondered if there were any specifics. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know...if its native mobile application try sending IMEI no , or UUID along with each request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have never come across what you have suggested. Could you please expand on your answer.

Comment: As far as I know , If its native mobile application.... try retriving IMEI no or UUID for the device which is unique for the device. Its how google or apple recognize there Devices for push notifications and other tasks. I 'm specialized in Android OS but don't know much about other platforms.